# How to set audio settings for AVCaptureAudioDataOutput in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, avcapturesession

I want to set the following audioSettings for AVCaptureAudioDataOutput, how can i do this?

```
 NSMutableDictionary *recordSettings = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatLinearPCM] forKey: AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100] forKey: AVSampleRateKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:705600] forKey:AVEncoderBitRateKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:16] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
```

```
self.audioRecorder = [[[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.audioRecorderDestinationFilePath] settings:recordSettings error:nil]autorelease];
```

[recordSettings release];

Comment: Did you got any answer or link for this.